# How to measure throughput in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to measure the throughput of read operations in Mongo. By throughput I mean  "how many reads the system process in a given amount of time (every second)".

I run `mongotop 1` and I get:

```
                 ns       total    read    write    2018-05-21T08:01:25Z

 sampledb.samplecol        57ms    25ms     32ms        

local.replset.minvalid     28ms     0ms     28ms  

     local.oplog.rs         9ms     9ms      0ms 

admin.system.indexes        0ms     0ms      0ms  

admin.system.namespaces     0ms     0ms      0ms  

 admin.system.roles         0ms     0ms      0ms   

 admin.system.users         0ms     0ms      0ms    

admin.system.version        0ms     0ms      0ms   

           local.me         0ms     0ms      0ms   

  local.startup_log         0ms     0ms      0ms
```

Is this means that the throughput of read operations is 25ms?

Comment: What is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: The version is: 3.0.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) The [mongotop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#bin.mongotop) provides a method to track the amount of time a MongoDB instance spends reading and writing data. [mongotop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#bin.mongotop) provides statistics on a per-collection level. By default, mongotop returns values every second.

Run [mongotop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#bin.mongotop) from the system command line, not the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell.

By default [mongotop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#bin.mongotop) connects to the MongoDB instance running on the localhost port 27017. However, mongotop can optionally connect to remote [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) instances.

For Example to force mongotop to return less frequently specify a number, in seconds at the end of the command. In this example, mongotop will return every 15 seconds.

```
mongotop 15
```

This command produces the following output:

```
ns    total    read    write          2014-12-19T15:32:01-05:00
     admin.system.roles      0ms     0ms      0ms
   admin.system.version      0ms     0ms      0ms
               local.me      0ms     0ms      0ms
         local.oplog.rs      0ms     0ms      0ms
 local.replset.minvalid      0ms     0ms      0ms
      local.startup_log      0ms     0ms      0ms
   local.system.indexes      0ms     0ms      0ms
local.system.namespaces      0ms     0ms      0ms
   local.system.replset      0ms     0ms      0ms

                     ns    total    read    write          2014-12-19T15:32:16-05:00
     admin.system.roles      0ms     0ms      0ms
   admin.system.version      0ms     0ms      0ms
               local.me      0ms     0ms      0ms
         local.oplog.rs      0ms     0ms      0ms
 local.replset.minvalid      0ms     0ms      0ms
      local.startup_log      0ms     0ms      0ms
   local.system.indexes      0ms     0ms      0ms
local.system.namespaces      0ms     0ms      0ms
   local.system.replset      0ms     0ms      0ms
```

> The output varies depending on your MongoDB setup.

***mongotop.read***

Provides the amount of time that this mongod spent performing read operations on this namespace.

***mongotop.write***

Provides the amount of time that this mongod spent performing write operations on this namespace.

> Is this means that the throughput of read operations is 25ms

**Yes**, In your case provides the amount of time that this mongod spent performing read operations on this namespace.

Comment: `mongotop` provides per-collection statistics on time spent reading and writing data. This is a measure of cumulative activity (time spent on read operations per collection) rather than throughput (number of read operations processed). `mongostat` would be more indicative of global system throughput.

Comment: @Stennie,The OP has run the command "mongotop" and also asked about the "read operation". Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

The [`mongostat` tool](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) provides you with this information.

Example output of `mongostat`:

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn     set repl                time
*0     2     *0     *0       0     2|0  0.0% 0.0%       0 3.18G 16.0M 0|0 1|0   556b   57.2k    2 replset  PRI May 22 09:17:02.431
```

From the example above, the `query` field has the value of `2`. This means that at that moment in time, the system processes two queries per second.

For full description of the output fields of `mongostat`, please see the [Fields section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#fields).

Comment: So mongostat can give information about records returned per second?